# Tensorflow's place holder's parameter shape as a list with None vale

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, placeholder

I am reading [this module](https://github.com/nvcuong/variational-continual-learning/blob/b0827e5bded789d6307d664413cc977893ae43ca/ddm/alg/cla_models_multihead.py) from this [github repo](https://github.com/nvcuong/variational-continual-learning). In Class_NN(), they have defined to placeholders:

```
def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, training_size):
    # input and output placeholders
    self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_size])# type and size of the input - why do we have [none,]?
    self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_size])
    self.task_idx = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
```

I know that the first parameter of tf.placeholder, tf.float32, is the type of value that x supposed to get and the second parameter is the shape of x as a tensor. Here the shape parameter is assigned as a list. What I don't understand is why the 0_indexed value in this list is None?

Comment: Hi @samsambakster, `None` means an unspecified dimension. So, if for example you define a placeholder, you use None to specify that this dimension can have any size. A placeholder can have multiple None dimensions. This means multiple dimensions can be of different sizes. Even the whole shape can be None to specify an unknown number of dimensions. Thank you!